# Как получить ближайшие города использую google maps api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, google-maps, геолокация

Задача - получить все города в радиусе 50км от заданной точки используя **google maps js api**

1) поиск мест поблизости, **nearbySearch** - при указании types: `['locality', 'administrative_area_level_3']` - возвращает только 2 города для каждого запроса, а надо получить ВСЕ города в радиусе. В доке не нашел про это ничего вообще.
если тип не указывать и парсить ответ самому - приходит максимум 60 мест, которые могут не включать в себя все города.

2) массовый поиск, **radarSearch** - нельзя указать городской тип, приходит 200 мест, в которых опять же могут не попасть города, и для каждого места надо посылать запрос с его `place_id` для определения город это или нет - это слишком накладно

3) сделал много меток, разместил их по границам вьюпорта карты и на некотором отдалении, проверяю каждую геокодированием находится в городе или нет - опять проблема - гугл не дает геокодировать больше 5 точек, только с перерывами в 2сек, это не подходит

подскажите что ещё можно попробовать

Comment: Можно попробовать [это](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html) (раздел "Country Subdivision / reverse geocoding"). С гугловыми картами я такого не видел, хотя вот [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135243/finding-towns-within-a-10-mile-radius-of-postcode-google-maps-api) похожую на Вашу задачу пытались решить с некоторыми оговорками.

Comment: этот сервис отдает города, но дальше мне надо работать с гуглом, чтобы получить границы этого города, в этом случае я могу взять координаты полученных мест и использовать геокодирование, но опять же упираюсь в 5 запросов, дальше идет превышение лимита на частоту запросов, а городов в радиусе может быть больше

Comment: Насколько я знаю, free аккаунт для посылки запросов имеет определенные ограничения. Возможно, они могут предложить некоторую подписку, которая увеличит возможности учетки. Честно скажу, что по этому поводу я ничего не узнавал, так что это просто мысли вслух, куда можно попробовать еще посмотреть =) Вот [тут](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits?hl=ru) описаны некоторые варианты оплаты. Правда там приводятся лимиты на день, т.е. запросы в секунду могут этим не регулироваться, а регулироваться исключительно настройками сервера

Answer (score 0):

Примените в строке запроса radius=5000, примерно так: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=48.859294,2.347589&radius=50&types=locality|administrative_area_level_3&key=zzzzzz`